# group by key with pandas series and export to_dict()

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, series

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
d = {1:0, 2:0, 3:1, 4:0, 5:2, 6:1, 7:2, 8:0}
```

And I want to group by .keys() such as I get:

```
pandas_ordered = { 0:[1,2,4,8], 1:[3,6], 2:[5,7] }
```

But with this command for

```
pd.Series(list(d.values())).groupby(list(partition.keys())).to_dict()
```

Bellow is an example:

```
# Example:
import pandas as pd

d = {1:0, 2:0, 3:1, 4:0, 5:2, 6:1, 7:2, 8:0} 


def pandas_groupby(dictionary):
   values = list(dictionary.values())
   keys = list(dictionary.keys())
   return pd.Series(values).groupby(keys).to_dict()


pandas_groupby(d)
```

The above code produces the error:

> AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'to_dict' of
>   'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You have to `agg` first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `dict` is already given by the `groups` in your `groupby`

```
d = {1:0, 2:0, 3:1, 4:0, 5:2, 6:1, 7:2, 8:0} 
s = pd.Series(d)
s.groupby(s).groups

{0: Int64Index([1, 2, 4, 8], dtype='int64'),
 1: Int64Index([3, 6], dtype='int64'),
 2: Int64Index([5, 7], dtype='int64')}
```

But of course, can always `agg` and customize

```
s.groupby(s).agg(lambda x: tuple(x.index)).to_dict()

{0: (1, 2, 4, 8), 1: (3, 6), 2: (5, 7)}
```

Comment: I should have thought that the answer would be that simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    pd.Series({1:0, 2:0, 3:1, 4:0, 5:2, 6:1, 7:2, 8:0},name='col1').reset_index()
.groupby("col1").agg(list)['index'].to_dict()
```

output:

```
{0: [1, 2, 4, 8], 1: [3, 6], 2: [5, 7]}
```